# How can I extract all the p values from a model for an individual factor variable?

Tags: r, p-value

Let's say I have factor variable Var_1 with 3 levels, "1", "2", and "3". "1" is the base level of the factor variable. So when I run a linear regression, I get a p value for each level of that variable. For example, the P value for "Var_12" is .05 and "Var_13" is .15. In this situation, the following code will work:

```
p_values <- summary(model_result)$coefficients[substr(names(coef(model_result)),1,nchar(test_var))==test_var,4]
```

Now, if I have another variable factor variable named "Var11" with levels "A" "B" and "C", and I run the model, and extract the p values with the code above, I am also going to get the p values from Var_11 because the substring from character 1 to 4 is Var_1, the same for "Var_1" and "Var_11".

I could rename the variables.
I could change the levels from "1" "2" and "3" to letters.

I don't really fancy either solution, is there a better solution for this? Is there a better way in general to extract the p values for one variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `term2coef` from the `remef` package allows you to extract the names of the coefficients based on the name of the model term.

Here is an example with a factor `Var_1` and the three levels `A`, `B`, and `C`.

```
set.seed(42)
dat <- data.frame(Var_1 = gl(3, 3, labels = c("A", "B", "C")),
                  y = rnorm(9))
dat
#   Var_1           y
# 1     A  1.37095845
# 2     A -0.56469817
# 3     A  0.36312841
# 4     B  0.63286260
# 5     B  0.40426832
# 6     B -0.10612452
# 7     C  1.51152200
# 8     C -0.09465904
# 9     C  2.01842371
```

A regression:

```
fit <- lm(y ~ Var_1, dat)
coef(summary(fit))
#                Estimate Std. Error    t value  Pr(>|t|)
# (Intercept)  0.38979623  0.5052336  0.7715168 0.4696854
# Var_1B      -0.07946076  0.7145082 -0.1112104 0.9150764
# Var_1C       0.75529933  0.7145082  1.0570898 0.3311624
```

In order to extract the p-values for `Var_1B` and `Var_1C`, the `remef` package needs to be installed from github.

```
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("hohenstein/remef")
```

The function `term2coef` extracts the names:

```
library(remef)
coefNames <- term2coef(fit, "Var_1")
coefNames
# [1] "Var_1B" "Var_1C"
```

Now, the p-values can be extracted:

```
coef(summary(fit))[coefNames, 4]
#    Var_1B    Var_1C 
# 0.9150764 0.3311624
```

---

(Disclaimer: I am the author of the `remef` package.)